# How to create and use my own structure/signature in SML/NJ?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm new to functional programming and I want to create my own structure/signature called Dictionary. So far I have this in file called dictionary-en.sml:

```
(* The signature DICTIONARY defines a type and a programming interface for
   the dictionary data structure. The data structure allows us to store
   data in the form of (key, value) pairs and to query the data using a key. *)
signature DICTIONARY =
sig

    (* The structure has to implement a dictionary type. It defines key type,
       which has to support equality checking, and a value type for the data
       stored in the dictionary. *)
    type (''key, 'value) dict

    (* Creates an empty dictionary. *)
    val empty: (''key, 'value) dict

    (* Returns true if a key exists in the dictionary. *)
    val exists: (''key, 'value) dict -> ''key -> bool

end
```

And I have this in file solution.sml:

```
structure Dictionary :> DICTIONARY =
struct
    type (''key, 'value) dict = (''key * 'value) list

    val empty = []

    fun exists dict key =
        case dict of
            [] => false
          | (k, _ )::rep => if k = key
                            then true
                            else exists rep key
end
```

But I don't how to use this.
When I wrote in REPL:

```
- Dictionary.exists [(3,"c"), (5, "e"), (7, "g")] 3;
```

I got this error:

```
stdIn:1.2-3.7 Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: (''Z,'Y) Dictionary.dict
  operand:         ([int ty] * string) list
  in expression:
    Dictionary.exists ((3,"c") :: (5,"e") :: (<exp>,<exp>) :: nil)
```

Can someone please help me? I don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the function

> ```
> fun exists dict key =
>     case dict of
>         [] => []
>       | (k, _ )::rep => if k = key
>                         then true
>                         else exists rep key
> ```

I spot two issues:

- You can't return `[]` in one place and `true` in another.
- Instead of `if P then true else Q`, write `P orelse Q`.

You're using `:>` which means that the module is [opaque](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/introsml/modules/sigstruct.htm), so you can only access the things specified in the signature. The internal list representation is not mentioned in the signature, so you can't refer to a *dict* as a list, even though you may know that that's how it's implemented. This is a feature.

I would probably call `exists` for `member`, since `List.exists` is a higher-order predicate, e.g. `List.exists (fn x => x > 5) [3, 6, 9]`. You could also deviate from any standard library naming and say `containsKey` and `containsValue`, or something like that.

Besides the `insert` function that molbdnilo suggested, you may like to have a `fromList` function.

Here's a refactored version (comments omitted for brevity, but I think your comments are good!):

```
signature DICTIONARY =
sig
    type (''key, 'value) dict

    val empty: (''key, 'value) dict
    val member: ''key -> (''key, 'value) dict -> bool
    val insert: (''key * 'value) -> (''key, 'value) dict -> (''key, 'value) dict
    val fromList: (''key * 'value) list -> (''key, 'value) dict
end

structure Dictionary :> DICTIONARY =
struct
    type (''key, 'value) dict = (''key * 'value) list

    val empty = []

    fun member key [] = false
      | member key ((key2, _)::dict) =
          key = key2 orelse member key dict

    fun insert (key, value) [] = [(key, value)]
      | insert (key, value) ((key2, value2)::dict) =
          if key = key2
          then (key, value) :: dict
          else (key2, value2) :: insert (key, value) dict

    fun fromList pairs = foldl (fn (pair, dict) => insert pair dict) empty pairs
end
```

---

But since you're building a dictionary module, there are two things you want to consider:

1. Make it possible to use some kind of binary tree as internal representation, requiring that the keys can be *ordered* rather than *compared for equality*.
2. Since Standard ML doesn't have special syntax like `''key` to express that something can be ordered (Haskell generalises this as [type classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class), but Standard ML has only the special syntax `''key`), this is a good case for using **functors**, which is the name given to higher-order modules, aka parameterised modules.

Here's an example signature, functor and structure that you can fill out:

```
signature ORD = sig
  type t
  val compare : t * t -> order
end

signature DICT = sig
  type key
  type 'value dict

  val empty: 'value dict
  val member: key -> 'value dict -> bool
  val insert: key * 'value -> 'value dict -> 'value dict
  val fromList: (key * 'value) list -> 'value dict
end

functor Dict (Ord : ORD) :> DICT = struct
  type key = Ord.t
  type 'value dict = (key * 'value) list

  val empty = ...
  fun member _ _ = raise Fail "not implemented"
  fun insert _ _ = raise Fail "not implemented"
  fun fromList _ = raise Fail "not implemented"
end
```

At this point you can change `type 'value dict` into using a binary tree, and when you need to decide whether to go left or right in this binary tree, you can write:

```
case Ord.compare (key1, key2) of
     LESS => ...
   | EQUAL => ...
   | GREATER => ...
```

And when you need a dictionary where the key is some particular *orderable* type, you can create a module using this functor:

```
structure IntDict = Dict(struct
                           type t = int
                           val compare = Int.compare
                         end)

structure StringDict = Dict(struct
                              type t = string
                              val compare = String.compare
                            end)
```

See also [Standard ML functor examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049882/standard-ml-functor-examples) for more examples.

Comment: I would just like to note, that if you change the functor to: functor Dict (Ord : ORD) :> DICT where type key = Ord.t You can "punch a hole" in the opaque Dict, allowing type key, to be an alias for int or string respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access the internal representation; the entire interface is given by the signature.
You need to add to the signature some way to create a dictionary without depending on the representation used in a particular structure.

For instance,

```
val insert : (''key * 'value) -> (''key, 'value) dict -> (''key, 'value) dict
```

would let you write

```
Dictionary.exists (Dictionary.insert (3,"c") Dictionary.empty) 3;
```

Implementation left as an exercise.